# Powershell: Colon in commandlet parameters

Tags: powershell

What's the deal with Powershell commandlet switch parameters that require a colon?

Consider Exchange 2010 management shell cmdlet [Move-ActiveMailboxDatabase](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd298068.aspx). The Confirm switch is a `System.Management.Automation.SwitchParameter` and must be used like so,

```
Move-ActiveMailboxDatabase -Confirm:$false
```

Without the colon the command fails to recognize the don't confirm switch like so,

```
Move-ActiveMailboxDatabase -Confirm $false
```

Why is that? What's the difference the colon makes there? Why Exchange2010 seems to be about the only thing I've noticed this behavior?

I've browsed through Powershell in Action and Powershell 2.0, but didn't find anything about this syntax. Scope resolution and .Net object access uses are documented on those books though.

My Google-fu found an [article](http://www.tellingmachine.com/post/The-PowerShell-Usage-Of-Colon-%28Punctuation%29-Under-The-Scope.aspx) which claims that it explicitly forwards switch parameter values, but fails to explain what that is about.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

When you do:

```
Move-ActiveMailboxDatabase -Confirm $false
```

you are not saying `Confirm` parameter accepts the `$false`. You are saying `-Confirm` and also passing an (separate) argument to the cmdlet with value `$false`.

Since `Confirm` is a switch, just the presence of `-Confirm` means it is true. Absence of `-Confirm` means it is false.

Let me give you a script example:

```
param([switch]$test)

write-host Test is $test
```

If you just run the script without any arguments / paramters i.e `.\script.ps1` you get output:

```
Test is False
```

If you run it as `.\script.ps1 -test`, the output is

```
Test is True
```

If you run it as `.\script.ps1 -test $false`, the output is

```
Test is True
```

If you run it as `.\script.ps1 -test:$false` the output is

```
Test is False
```

It is in scenarios where the value for a switch variable itself has to be determined from another variable that the `:` is used.

For example, consider the script:

```
param ([boolean]$in)

function func([switch] $test){
write-host Test is $test
}

func -test:$in
```

Here if you run it as `.\script.ps1 -in $false`, you get

```
Test is false
```

If you weren't able to use the `:`, you would have had to write it as:

```
if($in){  func -test}
else { func }
```

Comment: Not the full answer - I don't know about the Mailboxes example, but in many other cases (e.g. `Set-SMBServerConfiguration`), the effect of `-Confirm:$false` is different from its absence. I can use `-Confirm:$false` or `-Force`, otherwise I need to confirm.

Answer (score 8):

The colon can be used with every parameter value but is more special in the case of switch parameters. Switch parameters don't take values, they are either present ($true) or absent ($false).

Imagine you have a function like this:

```
function test-switch ([string]$name,[switch]$force) { ... }
```

And you call it like so:

```
test-switch -force $false
```

Since switch parameters are either present or not, $false would actually bind to the Name parameter. So, how do you bind a value to a switch parameter? With the colon:

```
test-switch -force:$false
```

Now the parameter binder knows which parameter the value goes to.