# Powershell: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument "xxx"

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to understand what this error actually means. So far a search of similar help requests for this error range from missing parameters, missing pipes, use of single or multi-lines, and also concatenation issues but none of the answers seem to give a definitive reason. So I assume the issue is code format (which makes it a lot harder to track down).

This is my script which I am writing to rename active directory users per target OU from whatever format they are now into a firstname.surname format.

I have created a test OU in AD with some users who will trigger errors and some that will not. However, the users that should not give me an error are giving me the "a positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument "firstname.surname"

I cannot see what is wrong with the script but hopefully, someone can give me some pointers.

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory

$users = $null

$users = Get-ADUser -SearchBase "ou=Testing,ou=Users,dc=my,dc=domain" -Filter * -Properties *
foreach ($user in $users) {
    Write-Host "Processing... $($user)"
    $newname = $null

    # Check first/last name is set
    if (!$user.givenName -or !$user.Surname) {
        Write-Host "$($user) does not have first name or last name set. Please correct, skipping user."
        continue
    } else {
        $newname = ("$($user.givenName).$($user.Surname)")

        #Check if new username already exists
        if (dsquery user -samid $newname) {
            Write-Host "$($user) requires altered username with initial."

            if (!$user.Initials) {
                Write-Host "$($user) does not have any initials set. Please correct, skipping user."
                continue
            }

            $newname = ("$($user.givenName)$($user.Initials).$($user.Surname)")

            #Check if altered new username already exists
            if (dsquery user -samid $newname) {
                Write-Host "$($user) requires manual change. Please correct, skipping user."
                continue
            }
        }

        try {
            #Change UPN
            Set-ADUser $user -userPrincipalName = $newname
            #Change DN
            Rename-ADObject -identity $user -Newname $newname
        } catch {
            Write-Host "Error when renaming $($user). Error is: $($_.Exception.Message). User requires manual change. Please correct, skipping user."
            continue
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Where the error occurs would be helpful instead of making us guess. Cursory glance says this is wrong `Set-ADUser $user -userPrincipalName = $newname`. Remove teh equals sign

Comment: Related post - [Powershell: Colon in commandlet parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8525572/465053)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Cmdlets in powershell accept a bunch of arguments.  When these arguments are defined you can define a position for each of them.

This allows you to call a cmdlet without specifying the parameter name.  So for the following cmdlet the path attribute is define with a position of 0 allowing you to skip typing -Path when invoking it and as such both the following will work.

```
Get-Item -Path C:\temp\thing.txt
Get-Item C:\temp\thing.txt
```

However if you specify more arguments than there are positional parameters defined then you will get the error.

```
Get-Item C:\temp\thing.txt "*"
```

As this cmdlet does not know how to accept the second positional parameter you get the error.  You can fix this by telling it what the parameter is meant to be.

```
Get-Item C:\temp\thing.txt -Filter "*"
```

I assume you are getting the error on the following line of code as it seems to be the only place you are not specifying the parameter names correctly, and maybe it is treating the = as a parameter and $username as another parameter.

```
Set-ADUser $user -userPrincipalName = $newname
```

Try specifying the parameter name for $user and removing the =

Answer (score 20):

I had this issue after converting my `Write-Host` cmdlets to `Write-Information` and I was missing quotes and parens around the parameters. The cmdlet signatures are evidently not the same.

> `Write-Host this is a good idea $here` 
>   `Write-Information this is a good idea $here`   <=BAD

This is the cmdlet signature that corrected after spending 20-30 minutes digging down the function stack...

> `Write-Information ("this is a good idea $here")`   <=GOOD

Comment: This was super helpful. I kept getting this error, but didn't know where it was being thrown from. Thank you!

Comment: lol, just adding parenthesis in second arg solved the problem, thanks

Comment: Am I smarter than a 5th grader? No, but @SilverNinja - MSFT is!

Answer (score 13):

I had this problem when trying to change directory, using the character `_`. The solution was to use a string to change directories.

```
C:\> cd "my_new_dir"
```

Answer (score 9):

In my case it was the *distinction* between `–` (em dash) and `-` (hyphen) as in:

```
Add-Type –Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
```

and:

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
```

[Dashes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash), [Hyphens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyphen), and [Minus signs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plus_and_minus_signs#Minus_sign) oh my!

Answer (score 1):

In my case there was a corrupted character in one of the named params ("-StorageAccountName" for cmdlet "Get-AzureStorageKey") which showed as perfectly normal in my editor (SublimeText) but Windows Powershell couldn't parse it.

To get to the bottom of it, I moved the offending lines from the error message into another .ps1 file, ran that, and the error now showed a botched character at the beginning of my "-StorageAccountName" parameter.

Deleting the character (again which looks normal in the actual editor) and re-typing it fixes this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use

```
powershell.AddCommand("Get-ADPermission");
powershell.AddParameter("Identity", "complete id path with OU in it");
```

to get past this error

Comment: ```powershell.AddCommand : The term 'powershell.AddCommand' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function,
script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path
is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ powershell.AddCommand("Get-ADPermission");```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar challenge when writing a **Powershell** script to interact with **AWS CLI** using the **AWS Powershell Tools**

I ran the command:

```
Get-S3Bucket // List AWS S3 buckets
```

And then I got the error:

> Get-S3Bucket : A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument list

**Here's how I fixed it**:

`Get-S3Bucket` does not accept `// List AWS S3 buckets` as an attribute.

I had put it there as a comment, but it's not acceptable by the **AWS CLI** as a comment. **AWS CLI** rather sees it as a parameter.

I had to do it this way:

```
#List AWS S3 buckets
Get-S3Bucket
```

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had tried to make code more readable by putting:

```
"LONGTEXTSTRING " +
"LONGTEXTSTRING" +
"LONGTEXTSTRING"
```

Once I changed it to

```
LONGTEXTSTRING LONGTEXTSTRING LONGTEXTSTRING
```

Then it worked