# Set-MalwareFilterPolicy example given by Microsoft documentation fails

Tags: powershell, exchange-server-2016, exchange-management-shell

I'm trying to add file types to Exchange Server 2019 malware policy. For that purpose, I follow Microsoft documentation shown at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/antispam-antimalware/set-malwarefilterpolicy?view=exchange-ps

Example 2 is exactly what I need:

```
$FileTypesAdd = Get-MalwareFilterPolicy -Identity Default | select -Expand FileTypes; $FileTypesAdd += "com","bat"; Set-MalwareFilterPolicy -Identity Default -EnableFileFilter $true -FileTypes $FileTypesAdd
```

Unfortunately, when I execute that example inside Exchange Management Shell, I get the following error message:

> A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'EnableFileFilter'.
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Set-MalwareFilterPolicy], ParameterBindingException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NamedParameterNotFound,Set-MalwareFilterPolicy
>       + PSComputerName        : exchange.bndt.local

I run Exchange Server 2016 (CU14) on a local Windows Server 2016 (Fully up-to-date).
I don't clearly understand what is wrong.

Any help appreciated.

Regards

Comment: Back in the days, Exchange cmdlets required colons to [pass switch parameter values](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8525572/503046); maybe this is such a case too? Try adding a colon to the parameter `-EnableFileFilter:$true`

Comment: Adding a colon results in the very same error.

Comment: The erreor "NamedParameterNotFound" makes me thinking that there is a typo in the cmdlet. Is the source available somewhere?

Comment: Maybe [a hack](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/luisdem/2016/05/19/get-the-source-code-of-the-powershell-cmdlets/) via `Get-Command` and ILSpy would be of use.

Comment: Altough it works as expected for Get-date, the hack you mention doesn't display anything for Set-MalwareFilterPolicy.

Comment: Maybe -EnableFileFilter requires a special permission? I'm logged with permission groups domain admin, enterprise admin, schema admin and origanization management.