# Disable the banner message printed after a command is invoked in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-remoting

```
PS C:\Windows\system32> Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $Credential | Out-Null

We have released new management cmdlets which are faster and more reliable.

|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|

| Old Cmdlets | New/Reliable/Faster Cmdlets |

|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
| Get-CASMailbox | Get-EXOCASMailbox |
| Get-Mailbox | Get-EXOMailbox |
etc.
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------|
```

Connect-ExchangeOnline always prints this banner message whenever the command is invoked.
How to disable this from getting printed.

Steps I tried:

```
- Piping to Out-Null.
- Assigning to $null.
- Invoking the command with -NoLogo attached
        Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $Credential -NoLogo
```

The command banner is getting printed even then.

I cannot change the way the PowerShell process is getting invoked as there is a wrapper layer that is calling the PowerShell.

The only modification that can be made is in the PowerShell script.

Comment: Does `-ShowBanner:$false `switch help?

Comment: It is working. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is poorly documented, as [Connect-ExchangeOnline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/powershell-v2-module/connect-exchangeonline?view=exchange-ps) doesn't mention `-ShowBanner:$false` switch, as [Use the Exchange Online PowerShell V2 module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/exchange/exchange-online/exchange-online-powershell-v2/exchange-online-powershell-v2?view=exchange-ps) page does.

To disable the banner, pass `$false` as `ShowBanner` switch parameter. Exchange cmdlets are the odd man out there, as most cmdlets just require the switch presence. Not so with Exchange, which I wondered about [five years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8525572/503046). In Exchange cmdlets, switch values need to be specified too.